# For-loop using dictionary key reference not working

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have never used Python before but have decided to start learning it by manipulating some market data. I am having trouble using the dictionary structures. In the code for *read_arr_price* below the command **dict_price_recalc[price_id][year_to_index(year), Q] = float(line2)/7.5** assigns **float(line2)/7.5** to all arrays, regardless of their **price_id** affiliation. I wonder if it is because I didn't initialize *dict_price* correctly.

```
def read_dict_price(dat_filename, dict_price):

## Load data set 
    dat_file = open(dat_filename,'r')
## Copy arr_price
    dict_price_recalc = dict_price

## Iterate through each row in the data set, assigning values to variables
    for line in dat_file:

        year = int(line[11:15])

        price_id = line[0:4]
        Q = 0
        Q1 = line[19:21]
        Q2 = line[23:25]
        Q3 = line[27:29]
        Q4 = line[31:33]

## Truncate year_list to prepare for another run of the nested loop
        year_list = []
        year_list[:] = []
## Repopulate
        year_list = [Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4]


#### This is where the mistake happens #### 
   ## Iterate through each row in year_list, populating dict_price_recalc with price data

        for line2 in year_list:
            dict_price_recalc[price_id][year_to_index(year), Q] = float(line2)/7.5

            Q += 1

return dict_price_recalc
```

My code initializing *dict_price* is below:

```
def init_dict_price(dat_filename):

    price_id= {}
    dat_file = open(dat_filename,'r')
    np_array = np.zeros(shape=(100,4)) # Zeros as placeholders
    np_array[:] = np.NaN
    for line in dat_file:
        key = line[:11]
        price_id[key] = np_array
return price_id
```

I appreciate any pointers you can provide.

Comment: your indentation is not right for `read_dict_price`

Comment: Yep, sorry about that. Corrected now.

Comment: `dict_price_recalc = dict_price` this assigns the same dictionary to the other variable, it doesn't copy the dictionary. Use `dict_price_recalc = dict_price.copy()` instead.

Comment: Also it seems the key for price_id is a string (`line[:11]`) but you are trying to use a tuple to access it (`[year_to_index(year), Q]`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line `price_id[key] = np_array` is setting the same array to each key so every key points to the same array. you probably meant `price_id[key] = np_array.copy()`

Comment: Yeah I found this a weird feature of numpy when I first started using it. What is the philosophy for doing it this way? Kind of unwieldy.

Comment: well its not just for numpy, its an attribute for pretty much any non-simple (lists, dicts, etc) objects because in reality, the variable is a reference to that data, much like c pointers. the `.copy()` creates a new instance of that object with the exact same values rather than just having the variable point to the same instance

Comment: It is important to understand the difference between mutable and immutable objects.  It can be quite useful to have a mutable object in several places at once (lists, dicts,etc).

Comment: I was more referring to the fact that the array is a consistent reference. When you loop through and assign a (regular) list to another list or a dictionary, it doesn't create a reference to that variable, it only copies its values. I am not experienced with numpy, but I don't know any situations where it would be useful to create a reference to the variable instead of copying it.